# How can i get html content or bytes of a rich text field in XPages?

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, richtext

I have 2 text fields and 1 rich text field in an XPage. I have created a mechanism that whenever there is a change in at least one of these fields the document is autosaved as draft.

My problem with rich text field is that i can catch changes in text but i cant catch changes in text style (i.e: if i bold some characters).

So i want to get rich text content as html or bytes or anything that changes together with styling.

I want to compare the content stored in the document and the new content in the client so i need something like doc.getItemValueAsHTML() != richField.getValueAsHTML() ...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The NotesXspDocument method getValue() followed by getHTML() gives you the HTML representation of the rich text field.

So use your data source and call the getValue() and getHTML() methods using the name of the field as parameter. Example:

```
document1.getValue("rtfield").getHTML()
```

Comment: i ve used myXspDocName.getValueAsString("richitem") but it gets only the text

Comment: @PerHenrikLausten: With a NotesXSPDocument you need to call `document1.getValue("rtfield").getHTML()` to get the HTML representation.

Comment: Doh! Of course - and that's exactly what I do here: http://per.lausten.dk/blog/2012/12/xpages-dynamically-updating-rich-text-content-in-a-ckeditor.html. I will update my answer

Comment: old value is stored in the document and new value is written in the field. When you want to compare the two you must get document1.getDocument().getItemValueString("fff") which returns only the old value text. If you use document1.getValueAsString("fff") it returns the new value since it is written in the yet-not-saved xsp document so it results in comparing new value with new value and not with old value.

Comment: True, I was merely answering your question on "How can I get html content or bytes of a rich text field in XPages?"

Comment: I'm still not sure that NotesDocument.getItemValueString("rtfield") returns the exact same string as NotesXSPDocument.getValue("rtfield").getHTML(). This might work if your richtext contains only text, but I doubt it does if you have for example inline images or base64-encoded images in the html...

Comment: ... To prevent problems when comparing the html content, you could first wrap the original NotesDocument into a NotesXspDocument: `docOriginal:NotesDocument=document1.getDocument(); document2:NotesXspDocument=com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.wrapped.DominoDocument.wrap(docOriginal.getParentDatabase().getFilePath(),docOriginal,null,null,false,null);` and afterwards compare the html returned by the NotesXspDocuments: `if (document1.getValue("rtfield").getHTML()==document2.getValue("rtfield").getHTML()) ...`

Comment: Alternatively, store the original value in a view scope variable and then use this variable for comparison with the new value

Answer (score 0):

I ve found a way eventually so i am pasting it here:

```
var rich1:com.ibm.xsp.component.xp.XspInputRichText = getComponent("rich1");
var richVal:com.ibm.xsp.component.xp.XspOutputText = getComponent("richVal");

var r = rich1.getValueAsString();
var i = ddoc1.getDocument().getFirstItem("rch");
var dd = i.getMIMEEntity().getContentAsText();
richVal.setValue(dd+"----"+ r +"!!!!!"+ ddoc1.getItemValueString("rch"));
```

it seems to be working.